# Which is preferable: delegate {} or () => {}

Tags: c#

I was wondering today if there's any reason to prefer using *delegate {}* instead of *() => {}*, in the cases where you need an empty function.

Do you know any reason to prefer one over another?

Comment: go for the one you find most readable. I prefer the latter, but that's just my subjective preference

Comment: Why are people voting to close this?  This is a perfectly valid question.  As far as the OP is concerned there may be a difference that he's overlooked.  The question police are at it again!

Comment: I'd like to remind everyone that we're here to help people.  Not every question has to be in depth and technical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're not the same thing.

Since `delegate {}` does not supply an argument list, it [can be converted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to a delegate that returns `void` and takes any number of arguments (except `ref`and `out` parameters).

This is not the same as `() => {}`, which is explicitly declared as taking no argument.

Comment: I didn't knew I could write: Action<int, int, int> f = delegate {}; Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe they're compiled into the same code (if the lambda gets compiled into a delegate not an expression, which it would if used where a delegate would be used).

My preference is for lambda, mainly because it's fewer characters and *i* don't think it's any less readable.